# If function is Riemann integrable on a closed interval, does it have a primitive function on the interval?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

I'm trying to solve the following theoretical question:

> If function is Riemann integrable on interval [a,b], does it have a
>   primitive function on [a,b]?

My solution is the following:

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1, & x\in \left [ 0,2 \right )\\ 
2, & x\in \left [ 2,4 \right ]
\end{matrix}\right.$

The following function is Riemann integrable on [0,4] but a primitive function does not exist on interval [0,4]. Therefore the statement is not correct. Is it correct? If not, could you help me fix it?

Comment: $f(x)$ must also be continuous over $[a,b]$.

Comment: What definition of "primitive" are you using?  Some definitions would allow the accumulation function of your example as a having a derivative. (It belongs to the first Baire class.)

Comment: @B.Goddard $F'(x)=f(x)$ for every $x \in I$ on an open interval I, for functions $F$ and $f$ defined on interval $I$

Comment: @MostafaAyaz: discontinuous functions can have primitives as well. A discontinuous function with jump discontinuity is guaranteed to have no primitives (consider example given in this question). But with other discontinuities there may be primitives. For example if $f(x) =2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x),f(0)=0$ has the primitive $F(x) =x^2\sin(1/x),F(0)=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false. There are many functions that are not the derivative of anything, yet they may have integrals.

In particular, no function with a simple discontinuity is a derivative. Thus, any such function that is bounded will serve as counterexample.

Comment: Is my sollution correct then?

Comment: @Martin Yes, that's an example of a function that could have no primitive, yet is integrable.

Answer (score 0):

The wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus is quite informative on the subject.

If you consider purely Riemann integration you are stuck with the need for continuity of $f$.

But if you allow for generalisations (Lebesgue, KH), then you get the notion of equality *almost everywhere* of $F'$ and $f$.

In paragraph **Generalizations** of the above article you can read:

```
However, if F is absolutely continuous, it admits a derivative F′(x) at almost every
point x, and moreover F′ is integrable, with F(b) − F(a) equal to the integral of F′ 
on [a, b]. Conversely, if f is any integrable function, then F as given in the first 
formula will be absolutely continuous with F′ = f a.e.
```

Yet, here with a finite number of points of discontinuity, you can nevertheless apply the paragraph called **Second part** or Newton Leibniz's axiom.

That is if you define $F(x)=x,\ 2x-2$ on the respective intervals you get that $F'=f$ in any closed interval $K\subset[0,2)\text{ or }(2,4]$ (namely in any $[0,2-\epsilon]$ or $[2+\epsilon,4]$).